# having error "Unfortunately you ### application has stopped"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

**This is a food recipe application and I am just learning so if you could please help me rectify my error and explain, I will be so grateful. Thanks in advance**

### Main activity

```
package rice.recipe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RiceActivity extends Activity {
    private RiceRecipeDataSource ds;
    private ListView recipelistview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rice);
        ds=new RiceRecipeDataSource();
        recipelistview=(ListView)findViewById(rice.recipe.R.id.listView1);
        recipelistview.setAdapter(new RiceRecipeDataSourceAdapter(this,ds ));


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rice, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

### ADAPTER code

```
package rice.recipe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RiceRecipeDataSourceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        private Context mycontext;
        private LayoutInflater myinflater;
        private RiceRecipeDataSource mydatasource;

        public RiceRecipeDataSourceAdapter(Context ctx,RiceRecipeDataSource ds)
        {
            mycontext=ctx;
            mydatasource=ds;
            myinflater=(LayoutInflater)mycontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mydatasource.getDataSourceLength();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView thumbnail;
            TextView name;

            if (convertView==null)
                convertView=myinflater.inflate(rice.recipe.R.layout.activity_rice, parent,false);
            thumbnail=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(rice.recipe.R.id.imageView1);
            thumbnail.setImageResource(mydatasource.getPhotoPool().get(position));
            name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById((rice.recipe.R.id.textView1));
            name.setText(mydatasource.getDishesPool().get(position));

            return convertView;

        }

    }
```

### DATA SOURCE code

```
package rice.recipe;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RiceRecipeDataSource
{
  private ArrayList<Integer> photoPool;
  private ArrayList<Integer> descriptionPool;
  private ArrayList<Integer> dishesPool;


public ArrayList<Integer> getPhotoPool() 
{
    return photoPool;
}
public ArrayList<Integer> getDescriptionPool()
{
    return descriptionPool;
}
public ArrayList<Integer> getDishesPool() 
{
    return dishesPool;
}
public RiceRecipeDataSource()
{
photoPool=new ArrayList<Integer>();
descriptionPool=new ArrayList<Integer>();
dishesPool=new ArrayList<Integer>();

setupPhotopool();
setupDescriptionpool();
setupDishespool();
}
public void setupPhotopool()
{

    photoPool.add(rice.recipe.R.drawable.jollofrice);
    photoPool.add(rice.recipe.R.drawable.friedrice);
    photoPool.add(rice.recipe.R.drawable.spaghetti);
    photoPool.add(rice.recipe.R.drawable.coconutrice);
    photoPool.add(rice.recipe.R.drawable.ricenbeans);
    photoPool.add(rice.recipe.R.drawable.whiterice);

}

public void setupDishespool()
{
    dishesPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.jellof);
    dishesPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.fried_rice);
    dishesPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.spag);
    dishesPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.coconut);
    dishesPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.rice_beans);
    dishesPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.plain_rice);

}

public void setupDescriptionpool()
{
    descriptionPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.jellof_desc);
    descriptionPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.friedr_desc);
    descriptionPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.spag_desc);
    descriptionPool.add(rice.recipe.R.string.coconut_desc);
}

public int getDataSourceLength()
{
    return photoPool.size();

}
}
```

### This is my LogCat

```
04-03 05:47:34.217: D/dalvikvm(865): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 6% free 2657K/2816K, paused 78ms, total 83ms
04-03 05:47:34.237: I/dalvikvm-heap(865): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.783MB for 1127536-byte allocation
04-03 05:47:34.317: D/dalvikvm(865): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3756K/3920K, paused 80ms, total 80ms
04-03 05:47:34.421: D/dalvikvm(865): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3760K/3920K, paused 13ms+20ms, total 108ms
04-03 05:47:34.697: D/AndroidRuntime(865): Shutting down VM
04-03 05:47:34.697: W/dalvikvm(865): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at rice.recipe.RiceRecipeDataSourceAdapter.getView(RiceRecipeDataSourceAdapter.java:52)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-03 05:47:34.778: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="rice.recipe"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="rice.recipe.RiceActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.main" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### after editing, new logcat

```
04-03 07:23:36.608: D/dalvikvm(933): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 46K, 6% free 2657K/2824K, paused 175ms, total 179ms
04-03 07:23:36.631: I/dalvikvm-heap(933): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.783MB for 1127536-byte allocation
04-03 07:23:36.709: D/dalvikvm(933): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3756K/3928K, paused 75ms, total 75ms
04-03 07:23:36.858: D/dalvikvm(933): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 3771K/3928K, paused 13ms+19ms, total 153ms
04-03 07:23:37.161: D/AndroidRuntime(933): Shutting down VM
04-03 07:23:37.161: W/dalvikvm(933): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at rice.recipe.RiceRecipeDataSourceAdapter.getView(RiceRecipeDataSourceAdapter.java:52)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-03 07:23:37.248: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What line is 52 at RiceRecipeDataSourceAdapter.java?

Comment: thumbnail.setImageResource(mydatasource.getPhotoPool().get(position));

Comment: @hopez First check mydatasource.getPhotoPool().get(position) have any value or not

Comment: @hopez Try my answer.. that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not following the Adapter customization properly. Check [this](http://vsvydenko.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-use-viewholder.html) . Your getView should be like the given code snippet. Can also check [this](http://antoine-merle.com/listview-optimisations-part-1-the-viewholder/)

Comment: can u please explain this line? holder.text.setText(DATA[position]); 
           holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

Comment: He is setting the data in the listview row. Data may be the array he has created. Second line has the logic to decide which icon to be displayed. Importantly what you should look for is ViewHolder  class you declare the widgets (layout components) of "rice.recipe.R.layout.activity_rice". And set their values after else condition.